# MPMoviePlayer controller doesn't play a video

Tags: iphone, ios, ios6, mpmovieplayercontroller

I'm developing an app that needs to play a video using Xcode 4.5.2 and iOS 6.0.

I'm using MPMoviePlayerController to play a video. I've followed  [this tutorial](http://mobile.tutsplus.com/tutorials/iphone/mediaplayer-framework_mpmovieplayercontroller_ios4/). But,still i'm not able to play a video in the simulator.

Here is my code :

```or-tag-here
- (IBAction)playVideo:(id)sender {
 NSString *filepath   =   [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Movie-1" ofType:@"mp4"];
 NSURL    *fileURL    =   [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
 MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:fileURL];
 moviePlayerController.shouldAutoplay =YES ;
 moviePlayerController.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleDefault ;
 moviePlayerController.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeFill ;
 [moviePlayerController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 360, 200)];
 [self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
 [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self
                                          selector:@selector(moviePlaybackComplete:)
                                             name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                           object:moviePlayerController];
[moviePlayerController play ] ;

}

- (void)moviePlaybackComplete:(NSNotification *)notification
{
    MPMoviePlayerController *moviePlayerController = [notification object];
    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self
                                                    name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification
                                                  object:moviePlayerController];

    [moviePlayerController.view removeFromSuperview];
}
```

I've already looked at many SO questions,but none of them solved my problem. I've also tried to create a **containerView** and add my `MPMoviePlayerController`into my **containerView**. I didn't make it work.

I've also tried to `MPMoviePlayerViewController`,so far i'm able to make it work. Another problem with it,i cannot `setFrame` to `MPMoviePlayerViewController`. But, I want to setFrame to my video player. It's not possible that its size can be fullscreen. Because,i need to display some buttons below my video player.

Do you guys have any idea how can i accomplish that ?

Edit : Console output

```or-tag-here
2012-12-19 16:29:21.554 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:21.555 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:21.565 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:27.230 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:27.231 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:27.241 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:27.706 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:27.707 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:27.718 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:27.919 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:27.920 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:27.930 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:28.077 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:28.077 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:28.088 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:28.219 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:28.220 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:28.230 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:28.368 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:28.368 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:28.382 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:28.511 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:28.512 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:28.521 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
2012-12-19 16:29:28.692 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay for pause
2012-12-19 16:29:28.692 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Disabling autoplay
2012-12-19 16:29:28.702 Coverzzz[4952:c07] [MPAVController] Autoplay: Skipping autoplay, disabled (for current item: 1, on player: 0)
```

Comment: add [moviePlayerController prepareToPlay ] ; before [moviePlayerController play ] ; If it is not working check the path of file

Comment: I've already tried prepareToPlay method,it has no effect, just twice console output. The path of file is correct too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I finally made this work. After iOS 5.0, `MPMoviePlayerController` needs to be declared as a property. So,i add that as a property and it worked.

Comment: without declared property you can use that :)

Answer (score 0):

Could you try this code :

```
MPMoviePlayerViewController *mp = [[MPMoviePlayerViewController alloc] initWithContentURL:_urlToLoad];
[self presentModalViewController:mp animated:YES];
```

instead of :

```
[self.view addSubview:moviePlayerController.view];
```

Hope this will help. Cheers.

Comment: It's not possible,If i do that, the app will crash,because u cant give  moviePlayerController as a parameter to presentModalViewController. Tested,crashed

Comment: Oh i see, Because you used MPMoviePlayerController that not MPMoviePlayerViewController that why it did't work for my answer. i will edit my answer. best.

Comment: Could you try with MPMoviewPlayerController? I'm used this class to handle youtube video and that work fine for me. Hopefully it could help.

Comment: Thank you,i found the solution and explained in my answer. The tutorial was old,so this was the problem. MPMoviePlayerController needs to be declared as a property.